# How to change the color of rect when mouse over by js?

Tags: javascript, svg

I write this code,but turns out it can't change the color of rect when mouse over,could anyone tell me where is wrong and how can I fix it, please?`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 21.0.2, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 288 560" style="enable-background:new 0 0 288 560;" xml:space="preserve">
<rect id="haha" x="83.4" y="130.7" width="121.2" height="115.2" style="fill:#FFFF00" onmouseover="a()" onmouseout="b()"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
function a(){
var ab=document.getElementById('haha');
ab.style.color="fill:#FFAEB9";
}
function b(){
var ab=document.getElementById('haha');
ab.style.color="fill:#FFFF00";
}
</script>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are accessing the `color` rule, which will change the text color of an HTML element. Just use the `fill`rule on the `style` property.

```js
function a(){
  var ab=document.getElementById('haha');
  ab.style.fill = "#FFAEB9";
}
function b(){
  var ab=document.getElementById('haha');
  ab.style.fill = "#FFFF00";
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0" style="enable-background:new 0 0;" xml:space="preserve">
  <rect id="haha" x="0" y="0" width="120" height="120" style="fill:#FFFF00" onmouseover="a()" onmouseout="b()"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Fill does not go in color it goes in fill so you use `style.fill=`. It is its own style

```js
function a(){
var ab=document.getElementById('haha');
ab.style.fill ="#FFAEB9";
}
function b(){
var ab=document.getElementById('haha');
ab.style.fill="#FFFF00";
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 21.0.2, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 288 560" style="enable-background:new 0 0 288 560;" xml:space="preserve">
<rect id="haha" x="83.4" y="130.7" width="121.2" height="115.2" style="fill:#FFFF00" onmouseover="a()" onmouseout="b()"/>

</svg>
```